# Swift - Store JSON globally

Tags: json, swift, variables, global, store

i have this JSON array stored in my local variable:

```
let bigJsonArray = JSON(response)
```

my question is if there is any possibility to store this "bigJsonArray" in a global variable/session/cookie/config so i can access it in every view of my app ?

Anybody knows how to process this and could help me?

Greetings and thanks!

Comment: JSON array? Did you mean a parsed JSON file?

Comment: "Session" and "cookie" are typically used in reference to web servers. What's the context here? iOS app? OS X app? Something else? What kinds of data are you wanting to store? Configs that change rarely? Data downloaded from a server?

Comment: its an iOS App. i mean i retrieved asyncronous data from the web server. This response is parsed using SwiftyJSON-library, and i want to store this retireved data so i dont need to request it again. You know what i mean?

Comment: you can store your data into class instance and you can access it anywhere in your app.

Comment: but everytime i initialize the class the data is retrieved again from the web :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to define `bigJsonArray` as a global variable just by defining it outside of any class and the Swift compiler will understand it as a global variable and you can access it from anywhere in your code.

for example:

```
import UIKit

var bigJsonArray = JSON(response)

class a {
    var x = 0
}
```

that's of curse will not save the data if you killed the app, but from what I understand from your question you just need to be able to access it from all the app without resending a request to the server.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save the JSON data permanently, you just store the data that you received as a file, and the next time you need it, you read it from the file and parse it (there's actually a method for that) instead of downloading and parsing the data. Much easier than trying to store the parsed data.

If this is data that *can* be downloaded again, read the appropriate documentation to make sure the file isn't backed up, and is stored in a cache directory where the OS can remove it if space is tight.